# My foreach returns Warning: Illegal string offset 'productname'

Tags: php, session, foreach

This is my first ever time posting something on stackoverflow. I'm a relatively new programmer in the likes of Php and I have this assignment where I have to make a shopping cart

I apologise if this is messy or can't be made out. I have been searching on these forums for about 2 days now and I cant really find myself a solutio

Now my problem is as follows

I get my product data from the database -> then I click on a product -> it goes to a page where it adds the productid, productname and price to a session with array_push and then it ends up back on the same page with where the cart is (the cart is on the same page as the productline)

Now I received the session just fine and with var dumps I can see that the array is completely filled even in the foreach.

All I want to do is show the productid/productname/price seperatly.

> > array(6) { ["productid"]=> string(1) "6" ["productname"]=> string(11) "solexfiets6" ["price"]=> string(5) "12.99" [0]=> string(1) "5" [1]=> string(11) "solexfiets5" [2]=> string(5) "16.99" }

Up ahead is the code I am using. Maybe someone here can explain me what is going on

```
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION["cart"]) && count($_SESSION["cart"])> 0)
{

echo '<div id="cd-cart">';
echo '<h2>Cart</h2>';
echo '<ul class="cd-cart-items">';
echo '<li>';


foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $id => $value) {
    //var_dump($_SESSION["cart"]); // this var_dump
    //echo $id; //
    $products = $id;
    echo $value["productname"] . '<br/>';
}
echo '</li>';
echo '</ul>';
echo '<div class="cd-cart-total">';
echo '<p>Total <span>$39.96</span></p>';
echo '</div>';

echo '<a href="#0" class="checkout-btn">Checkout</a>';
echo '<p class="cd-go-to-cart"><a href="#0">Go to cart page</a></p>';
echo '</div>';

}
```

Thank you kindly for any help

```
     foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $id => $value) {
     print_r($value); //outputs 6solexfiets612.995solexfiets516.99 
     (it puts everything in the session in a string)

    //var_dump($_SESSION["cart"]);
    //echo $id; //
    //$products = $id;
    //echo $value["productname"] . '<br/>';
}
```

The way I send my products to this page is by sending the productid, productname and price in the url when someone clicks on order to add_to_cart.php which then does this

```
<?php
session_start();

if(empty($_SESSION['cart'])){
$_SESSION['cart'] = array();
}

array_push($_SESSION['cart'], $_GET['productid'], $_GET['productname'], $_GET['price']);



?>

 <p>Het product is toegevoegd aan uw winkelwagen</p> <a href="../cart.php">Naar winkelwagen</a>
```

By all the help I have received I found out that I'm sending the data the wrong way. Is there a better way to send the products to the cart and then looping through it?

I have made a followup question on this question right here with all the information on my code

[Sessions/foreach issue with my shopping cart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35677015/sessions-issue-with-my-shopping-cart)

I'm sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: I think i know what the problem is, but first, can you please put print_r($value) in your loop (where you have var_dump) and post the output into the question please :) - this may even answer your question when you see the output.

Comment: Thank you very much for assisting 
I have added the print_r($value) and now it puts the entire session like this. I'm sorry I still dont understand what the problem is !

Comment: $value is not an array... It will work like `$_SESSION['cart']["productname"]`

Comment: Offtopic: Good formatting considering that this is your first post. +1 from me just because of the formatting. Keep it up :)

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I'm still really struggling with this one so I hope that maybe in the followup question someone can resolve this for me !

Comment: it is wierd because your $_SESSION['cart'] is getting the right structure once, and then not again - somewhere, I think, you are putting stuff in $_SESSION['cart'] that is not the array_push above. Regardless - you want to do this: array_push($_SESSION['cart'], array('productid' => $_GET['productid'], 'productname' => $_GET['productname'], 'price' => $_GET['price'])); - what we are doing here is putting an array into your array (mental i know :P) which gives you an array of arrays that you can then foreach over (as below answer)

Comment: something else - if you don't want everything to be a string in your session - you can sort that out in the array push as well ($_GET is always strings) - you could check that, for instance if is_numeric($_GET['price']) == true then $_GET['price'] = (float)$_GET['price']; - we check that the value in price is a number, then we tell PHP we want it to store it as a number. http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK here is your problem -

You are iterating over the cart like it contains multiple items, when in fact, it contains only one.

I will give you a fully worked example to show you:

```
foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $id => $value){

ITERATION 1: 
    $id = “productid”
    $value = “6”

ITERATION 2: 
    $id = “productname”
    $value = “solexfiets6”

ITERATION 3: 
    $id = “price”
    $value = “12.99”

ITERATION 4: 
    $id = 0
    $value = “5”

ITERATION 5: 
    $id = 1
    $value = “solexfiets5”

ITERATION 6: 
    $id = 2
    $value = “16.99”

At no point in this iteration is there a valid variable called `$value[“productname"]` which is why your code fails.

}
```

You are treating `$_SESSION[‘cart']` as if it were an array of arrays, but it isn't and therefore, your loop is failing is because it can’t find `$value[“productname"]` in every iteration - or in any iteration (in this case)

An example of it working:

Run this code (here we are setting an array, with two arrays inside):

```
  $_SESSION['cart'] = array(
    0 => array( "productid" => 6, "productname" => "solexfiets6", "price" => 12.99 ),
    1 => array( "productid" => 5, "productname" => "solexfiets5", "price" => 16.99 )
  );

  print_r($_SESSION[‘cart']);
```

you will get this output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [productid] => 6
            [productname] => solexfiets6
            [price] => 12.99
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [productid] => 7
            [productname] => solexfiets5
            [price] => 16.99
        )

)
```

run this code:

```
 $_SESSION['cart'] = array(
    0 => array( "productid" => 6, "productname" => "solexfiets6", "price" => 12.99 ),
    1 => array( "productid" => 7, "productname" => "solexfiets5", "price" => 16.99 )
  );

  //this loop iterates twice because $_SESSION[‘cart’] has two ‘members’ - so we know we are seeing one product for every loop iteration
  foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $id => $value)
  {
    echo 'Product Name ' . $value["productname"] . '<br/>';
    echo 'Product ID ' . $value["productid"] . '<br/>';
    echo 'Product Price ' . $value["price"] . '<br/>';
    echo '<br/>';
  }
```

You will get this output:

```
Product Name solexfiets6
Product ID 6
Product Price 12.99

Product Name solexfiets5
Product ID 7
Product Price 16.99
```

And example of it not working (your current input is used as an example)

```
  //this is what your cart is currently set to
   $_SESSION['cart'] = array(
      "productid" => "6",
      "productname" =>  "solexfiets6",
      "price" => "12.99", 
      0 =>  "5",
      1 => "solexfiets5",
      2 => "16.99"
    );

  //this loop (which is like your loop) iterates 6 times because there are 6 items in the $_SESSION[‘cart’] array, i.e. it is not executing per-product as you expect.
  foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $id => $value)
  {
    echo 'the value is: ' . $value . '<br/>';
  }
```

will output

```
the value is: 6
the value is: solexfiets6
the value is: 12.99
the value is: 5
the value is: solexfiets5
the value is: 16.99
```

In summary, the structure of your input array is incorrect, it needs to be be an array of product arrays, not just a single-dimensional array of values if it should to work the way you want it.

Some general tips for debugging stuff like this

1.`print_r` is super cool (if you view the page source, you will see why - it prints stuff out well structured)
  2. `$value` and `$id` in your loop are what you care about, not the session - you should not be var_dumping your session in the loop as it is constant for the loop - you want to see what the `$value` and `$id` are (as these change each iteration)

A `foreach` loop will always iterate `count($n)` number of times where:

```
foreach ($n as $something)
{

}
```

In other words - if you have `$n` going into a foreach loop - you can see how many items it will iterate over by looking at `count($n)` - in your case, `count($_SESSION['cart'])` was 6, but you were expecting 2 - so you would have known immediately that something was wrong with the input data.

I am sorry I can’t give you the solution that will fix your problem, as the problem is with the input, however that input is very close to being right. You have everything in the session variable, it just needs to be formatted with the right structure. I hope I have helped you understand the data & how `foreach` loops work with examples :)

Comment: Thank you so much for this reaction I will look at your examples and try to edit it for it to work.

This was a huge help thank you (:

Comment: I would like to ask one more question to you if possible. I send my data too this page via an array_push which $_GETS the productid, productname and price data. Is there a better way I can send it?

Comment: i think you would need to ask a separate question with the full details in order to really understand what you are doing - i am guessing your approach is not perfect given the value of your session variable.