# Sessions/foreach issue with my shopping cart

Tags: php, session, shopping-cart

This question is actually a continuation from another question. I'd like to make sure I state all the details in this one.

I'm a relatively new programmer in the likes of Php and I have this assignment where I have to make a shopping cart

I get my product data from the database -> then I click on a product -> it goes to a page where it adds the productid, productname and price to a session with array_push and then it ends up back on the same page with where the cart is (the cart is on the same page as the productline)

**cart.class.php** -> this is the page where I originally receive the product data from. By using my getAllproducts(); I get all the data which I then loop through to make the 6 products appear.

```
<?php

class Cart
{
private $con;
private $productid;

function __construct(){
    $this->con = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=#', '#', '#');
}

public function getProductDataById($passedId){

    $this->productid = $passedId;

    $statement = $this->con->prepare("SELECT productname, productdescription, productimage, price FROM producten WHERE productid = :productid");
    $statement->execute(array("productId" => $this->productid));
    $data = $statement->fetch();

    return($data);
}
public function getAllproducts(){

    $statement = $this->con->prepare("SELECT productid, productname, productdescription, productimage, price FROM producten");
    $statement->execute();
    $data = $statement->fetchAll();

    return($data);
}
}
?>
```

Next I use **Cart.php** to show my products. On this page I loop through the products and then when someone clicks on order (bestellen) productid, productname and price will be send to add_to_cart.php

```
<?php
/*errors */
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);

/*Php classes */
require_once("../classes/cart.class.php");

$products = new cart();
$data = $products->getAllproducts();

?>
<title>Side Cart</title>
</head>
<body>
<header>
    <div id="cd-cart-trigger"><a class="cd-img-replace" href="#0">Cart</a></div>
```

```
<div class="container productline">
    <div class="row">
    <?php
    foreach($data as $value){

        echo '<div class="col-md-4 productcage">';
        echo '<h2 class="product_name">'.$value["productname"].'</h2>';
        echo '<p class="price_tag">€'.$value["price"].' euro</p>';
        echo '<p class="#">'.$value["productdescription"].'...</p>';
        echo '<a href="/shoppingcart/php/add_to_cart.php?productid='.$value["productid"] . "&productname=" . $value["productname"]. "&price=" . $value["price"].'" class="btn btn_order addcart">Add to cart <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span></a><br/><br/>';
        echo '</div>';
    }
    ?>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="cd-shadow-layer"></div>
 // Here's where the shopping cart starts 
<?php

session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION["cart"]) && count($_SESSION["cart"])> 0)
```

{

```
echo '<div id="cd-cart">';
echo '<h2>Cart</h2>';
echo '<ul class="cd-cart-items">';
echo '<li>';

 foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $id => $value)
{
    echo 'Product Name ' . $value["productname"] . '<br/>';
    echo 'Product ID ' . $value["productid"] . '<br/>';
    echo 'Product Price ' . $value["price"] . '<br/>';
    echo '<br/>';
}

echo '</li>';
echo '</ul>';
echo '<div class="cd-cart-total">';
echo '<p>Total <span>$39.96</span></p>';
echo '</div>';

echo '<a href="#0" class="checkout-btn">Checkout</a>';
echo '<p class="cd-go-to-cart"><a href="#0">Go to cart page</a></p>';
echo '</div>';

}

?>
```

Then I go to **add_to_cart.php**

This sends the session back to cart.php where below I want to loop the products in the shopping cart

```
<?php
 session_start();

 if(empty($_SESSION['cart'])){
 $_SESSION['cart'] = array();
 }

 array_push($_SESSION['cart'], $_GET['productid'], $_GET['productname'], $_GET['price']);

 ?>

  <p>Het product is toegevoegd aan uw winkelwagen</p> <a href="../cart.php">Naar winkelwagen</a>
```

**TL;DR when I try to loop through $value["productname"] my foreach returns Warning: Illegal string offset 'productname'**

I have no idea how to make all of this work because I'm still quite a beginner in PHP. If someone wants to take the time to figure out my stupid mistakes it would be very amazing.

I hope I have been clear enough. I apologise for the inconvenience

```
 foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $id => $value)
 {
    echo ($_SESSION[ 'cart' ][ $id ] . " " . $value); //1 1solexfiets1 solexfiets115.99 15.99
    var_dump(($_SESSION[ 'cart' ][ $id ] . " " . $value)); // string(3) "1 1" string(23) "solexfiets1 solexfiets1" string(11) "15.99 15.99"
}
```

I have changed the array_push to

```
 array_push($_SESSION['cart'], array('productid' => $_GET['productid'], 'productname' => $_GET['productname'], 'price' => $_GET['price']));
```

and when I print_r on cart.php I get the following back

```
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => solexfiets1 [2] => 15.99 [3] => Array ( [productid] => 1 [productname] => solexfiets1 [price] => 15.99 ) )
```

But when I try to loop through it like this

```
   foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $id => $value)
{
    echo 'Product Name ' . $value["productname"] . '<br/>';
    echo 'Product ID ' . $value["productid"] . '<br/>';
    echo 'Product Price ' . $value["price"] . '<br/>';
    echo '<br/>';
}
```

I still get the same error

> Warning: Illegal string offset 'productname'

So is there still something I'm doing wrong? I understand now that I need to send a collection of things instead of what I did before but I still can't quite understand why its failing now

**Thank you all very much for helping me!**
I seem to have solved the problem. I took everyone's advice and I finally have a working foreach statement. Now the products are ordered and will appear in the shopping cart

Again thanks to everyone who helped me out!

Comment: The problem is still in your input - but I can't work out how that input became mangled - this `Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => solexfiets1 [2] => 15.99 [3] => Array ( [productid] => 1 [productname] => solexfiets1 [price] => 15.99 ) )` is wrong - which is why your loop fails - somehow you are still adding the get variables to the session one by one (which is why $_SESSION['cart'][0], $_SESSION['cart'][1], $_SESSION['cart'][2] and $_SESSION['cart'][3] are set - can you make sure you clear the session completely and try again? `unset($_SESSION['cart']);` on a one-off page.

Comment: I just solved the problem actually! It seems that there was still some wrong information in the array. Sorry for all the effort you had to do and thank you very much for all the help. You've really taught me a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry I didn't see you had a new question so i posed this as a comment to your other one.

Replace your array_push with this one and let me know if that works out for you.

```
array_push($_SESSION['cart'], array('productid' => $_GET['productid'], 'productname' => $_GET['productname'], 'price' => $_GET['price']));
```

Your problem is that you are pushing related data into an array ($_SESSION['cart']) but not maintaining that relation - think of it this way:

$_GET is an array containing a bunch of data - when you reference a specific part of that array ($_GET['productname'] for instance) you are removing it from its collection and doing something with it - with your array_push you are simply pushing stuff into another array ($_SESSION['cart']) but not maintaining the relationship - so you push a bunch of stuff into $_SESSION['cart'] over and over again, and they all kind of get lost - they no longer maintain their relation to each other.

What we do is we push an array (collection) of the things you want, so $_SESSION['cart'] now contains several collections of things, instead of just the things.

Another way to think of this is - you could just do this:

```
array_push($_SESSION['cart'], $_GET);
```

this would have the same effect, as we are pushing the $_GET array into our other array, so the relationships are maintained - the reason you don't want to do this is because, in my example above, we create a new array with only the data we need. If we just push the whole $_GET array in there, we could end up with a bunch of other stuff we don't need (a user could put &someothervariable=aReallyReallyLongString) and then that would end up in our session as well.

Comment: Thank you very much for all the explaining its become a lot clearer to me now. However I still seem to get the illegal string offset error. I have edited the question and put all my findings there

Comment: Rick, To your comment 'Thank you very much for all the explaining its become a lot clearer to me now. However I still seem to get the illegal string offset error. I have edited the question and put all my findings there – Rick Spanjers 49 ' I solved that error initially. Add my solution to laMaCup's and it should work fine

Comment: I don't know if that is true - how is this happening in the session variable: Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => solexfiets1 [2] => 15.99 [3] => Array ( [productid] => 1 [productname] => solexfiets1 [price] => 15.99 ) ) - i.e. there are 0, 1, 2 and 3 array index's that should not be there - causing the error - i can't work out how they get into the session in the first place....

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    session_start();

    $_SESSION[ 'cart' ] = array();

    array_push( $_SESSION[ 'cart' ], array( 'productid' => 1, 'productname' => 'product1', 'productprice' => 15.99 ) );
    array_push( $_SESSION[ 'cart' ], array( 'productid' => 2, 'productname' => 'product2', 'productprice' => 4.99 ) );
    array_push( $_SESSION[ 'cart' ], array( 'productid' => 3, 'productname' => 'product3', 'productprice' => 17.99 ) );

    foreach( $_SESSION[ 'cart' ] AS $arr )
        echo $arr[ 'productname' ] . ' ';
?>
```